# Auto email when a cell is populated

Tags: google-sheets

I will explain since coding is many years behind me but I feel this can be done.

1. We have a form that our employees fill out when they need to return to a job. This works fine, sends them an email that it was received and creates the sheet in google.
2. We then have the CSR fill out their name once they set up the callback.
   Simple right?
   Yes and no.
   The employees know it was received but not that column c2 (or whatever) is now populated with the CSR name and was set.
   What I am looking to do is have column c2 trigger an email back to the employee who filled out the form with certain data from the google sheet so they know it was addressed, by who and when.
   I have seen similar codes but nothing that does exactly this. I can play with the column names etc. but I am cannot get it started.
   Yes, brand new with google sheets and the last programming I did was DOS and Advanced Revelatinos about 20 years ago.
   For argument sake here are the headers:
   Date employee_email Customer Address Reason date_needed set_up_date CSR (CSR would be the trigger and it would send the customer, address, set_up_date and CSR name to it.
   It sounds so simple yet after 6 hours at my EMT shift (less two calls) I have not gotten far.
   Thank you again.

Any help, direction or solution would be great!

Comment: Please provide us with a template of your spreadsheet to make it easy to help you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.